# How Can I fix Woocommerce Billing Address Field?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to fix the Woocommerce billing address field in my Wordpress website. This field is inside the "my account" tab. It looks weird and I do not know how can I fix it?

[image: This is what I want to say]

Note: "Fatura adresi" means billing address in Turkish.

Comment: Hey, It may be something related to your theme or CSS file.
Can you please change your theme and see if it is still breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by a specific css code.

```
.col-1{    
    flex: 0 0 50.333333%;
    max-width: 50.333333%;
}
```